# getElementById().value Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, undefined, getelementbyid

I am trying to store references to a multitude of inputs on my page in javascript variables to be passed to a webmethod on my backend. Because my page only pulls up and fills one of two hidden forms with data when the page loads some of the values of the inputs are 'undefined'. This throws an error that results in my webmethod to update a database never being called.

An example of one of my javascript call is as follows:

```
const fields = {
                    name: '<%=eventFormName.ClientID%>',
                    type: '<%=eventFormType.ClientID%>',
                    subjectLineSD: '<%=eventFormSubjectLineSD.ClientID%>',
                    summarySD: '<%=eventFormSummarySD.ClientID%>',
                    resourcesAffectedSD: '<%=eventFormResourcesAffectedSD.ClientID%>',
                    peopleAffectedSD: '<%=eventFormPeopleAffectedSD.ClientID%>',
                    workAroundSD: '<%=eventFormWorkAroundSD.ClientID%>',
                    startTimeSD: '<%=eventFormStartTimeSD.ClientID%>',
                    endTimeSD: '<%=eventFormEstimatedTimeOfResolutionSD.ClientID%>',
                    subjectLinePO: '<%=eventFormSubjectLinePO.ClientID%>',
                    summaryPO: '<%=eventFormSummaryPO.ClientID%>',
                    resourcesAffectedPO: '<%=eventFormResourcesBeingChangedPO.ClientID%>',
                    changeBenefitsPO: '<%=eventFormChangeBenefitsPO.ClientID%>',
                    impactOnEndUsersPO: '<%=eventFormImpactOnEndUsersPO.ClientID%>',
                    startTimePO: '<%=eventFormProposedStartDatePO.ClientID%>',
                    endTimePO: '<%=eventFormProposedEndDatePO.ClientID%>',
                }

                const values = Object.keys(fields).map((key) => {
                    const elm = document.getElementById(fields[key])
                    if (elm) {
                        return elm.value;
                    }
                    return null;
                })

                PageMethods.updateData.apply(this, values);
```

In other words, how could I allow for some of these variables to have value 'undefined' or 'null' to then be passed through my PageMethods call to my backend?

Also, here is my webmethod on the backend for reference:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string updateData(string[] values)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            command = new SqlCommand("updateNetEvent", sqlConn);

            if (values[1] == "Planned Outage")
            {
                // NetEvent Parameters
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", values[0]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", values[1]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubjectLine", values[9]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTime", values[14]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndTime", values[15]);

                // UserAction Parameters
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Summary", values[10]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResourcesAffected", values[11]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChangeBenefits", values[12]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PeopleAffected", System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImpactOnEndUsers", values[13]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkAround", System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "A");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerformedBy", "placeholder"); // TODO: Update
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerformedOn", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }
            else if (values[1] == "Service Disruption")
            {
                // NetEvent Parameters
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", values[0]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", values[1]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubjectLine", values[2]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTime", values[7]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndTime", values[8]);

                // UserAction Parameters
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Summary", values[3]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResourcesAffected", values[4]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChangeBenefits", System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PeopleAffected", values[5]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImpactOnEndUsers", System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkAround", values[6]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "A");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerformedBy", "placeholder"); // TODO: Update
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerformedOn", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }

            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlConn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConn.Close();
            return "./StartPage.aspx";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.ToString());     // Add a log helper to display errors here
            return "Error in updateData WebMethod";
        }

    }
```

Comment: make the fields that don't get filled set to N/A or something so they have a value but they are not being treated as undefined. Maybe have a default value for fields in case they do not get filled

Comment: What's the error? `Cannot read property 'value' of null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to get elements that do not exist, this is why you get thrown.  You need to check this, before you call `.value`.

```
var name = null
var nameElement = document.getElementById('<%=eventFormName.ClientID%>');
if (nameElement) {
  name = nameElement.value
}
```

EDIT:

Because it's bothering me a bit that your code is gonna be messy.  You could do something like this below to make things a bit more dynamic.  Replace the values for each of the properties with your asp tags and update how you call your `PageMethods.updateData` to `PageMethods.updateData.apply(this, values)`

```js
const fields = {
  name: 'name',
  type: 'type',
  subjectLineSD: '<%=eventFormSubjectLineSD.ClientID%>',
  summarySD: '',
  resourcesAffectedSD: '',
  peopleAffectedSD: '',
  workAroundSD: '',
  startTimeSD: '',
  endTimeSD: '',
  subjectLinePO: '',
  summaryPO: '',
  resourcesAffectedPO: '',
  changeBenefitsPO: '',
  impactOnEndUsersPO: '',
  starTimePO: '',
  endTimePO: '',
  endTimePO: ''
}

const updateData = function(name, type) {
  console.log(name)
  console.log(type)
}

const values = Object.keys(fields).map((key) => {
  const elm = document.getElementById(fields[key])
  if (elm) {
    return elm.value
  }
  return null
})

updateData.apply(this, values)
```

```html
<input id="name" value="NAME">
<input id="type" value="TYPE">
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the const updateData function? Is it just for debugging purposes? Also in the webmethod call on the back end now would I still need to write out each parameter being taken as a string?

Comment: I am now getting the error "PageMethods is not defined at updateClicked"

Comment: @FrankTheTank yeah the `updateData` is just an example for your `PageMethods.updateData`.  Do you want to post your updated code?

Comment: Yes I wrote a sql procedure to update the database and I have a webmethod on my backend that should be called but isn't quite yet, I will post the webmethod called on the server above so you can see

Answer (score 0):

Your error results from trying to get the value of an element not on the page.

If you call `var name = document.getElementById('foo')` but there is no element with `id='foo'` then the variable 'name' is null. Hence the error `Cannot read property 'value' of null`

If you set your variables first checking that the element exists, this should solve your problem e.g.

`var name = document.getElementById('foo') ? document.getElementById('foo').value : null;`

Comment: This is cleaner, but slight performance hit having to do an extra `getElementById` albeit minimal.